# Apache BasicAuth depending on request origin

Tags: apache-2.2, http-basic-authentication

I'm wondering if the following is possible somehow:

Make Apache ask for basic authentication when a resource is requested from the Internet and just bypass the authentication when a request originates from the local network. I found some info about the [satisfy directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#satisfy) after reading this [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/143948/apache-request-ip-based-security) but i cant make it work here the config snippet with which I try to achieve my goal:

```
<Directory /path/to/published/resource>
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName authname
    AuthUserFile /path/to/authfile
    Require user username
    Allow from 192.168.178
    Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

Any suggestions why that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the [order](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order) and try again:

```
<Directory /path/to/published/resource>
    AllowOverride All
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName authname
    AuthUserFile /path/to/authfile
    Require user username
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 192.168.178
    Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks works perfectly when switching Order allow,deny the other reformatting you did doesn't seems to have any influence, right?

Comment: Yes. I just move the `Order` line to above the `Allow from` line to follow more easily.